# How to print Arabic string in Bluetooth printer using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, arabic-support, bluetooth-printing

I want to print a receipt voucher in Arabic, but after printing the words appear in Chinese.
I'm using   [esc_pos_bluetooth](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_bluetooth) package to print via Bluetooth and I followed the steps in package example [here](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_bluetooth/tree/master/example/blue) .
this is the code to print:

```
Future<Ticket> getReceipt(PaperSize paper) async {
    final Ticket ticket = Ticket(paper);

    Uint8List encArabic =
        await CharsetConverter.encode("windows-1256", "اهلا");

    print("encArabic:$encArabic");
    ticket.textEncoded(encArabic,
        styles: PosStyles(codeTable: PosCodeTable.pc864_1));

    final now = DateTime.now();
    final formatter = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy H:m');
    final String timestamp = formatter.format(now);
    ticket.text(timestamp,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center), linesAfter: 2);
    ticket.cut();
    return ticket;
  }
```

The word "اهلا" should be printed in Arabic but it appears in Chinese.
For the printer that I'm using it was from an unknown company the only thing I knew about it  was the model: MHT-29L

Comment: Did you try this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer ?

Comment: @AnasSafi
No, but I will try it now.. thank you

Comment: @AnasSafi 
`bluetooth.printCustom("السلام ",2,1,charset: "UTF-8");`
is this the correct charset if true it appears in Chinese

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @MahmoudHajAli 
Yes I convert it into pdf the into Image then print the image it works for me
its the best way

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the character table for your printer and write the corresponding commands to let the printer know that you are printing multi byte characters such as Arabic characters. In my case, I was using sunmi printer and the only thing that worked for me was finding its character table and I wrote the commands and it worked very well. Here's a picture of what they said in the documentation.

[a picture of what they said in the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YQF5.png)

And this is what I did and it worked perfectly

```
const utf8Encoder = Utf8Encoder();
final encodedStr = utf8Encoder.convert(invoice.description);
bytes += generator.textEncoded(Uint8List.fromList([
  ...[0x1C, 0x26, 0x1C, 0x43, 0xFF],
  ...encodedStr
]));
```

Comment: How it work `bytes += generator.textEncoded(Uint8List.fromList([
  ...[0x1C, 0x26, 0x1C, 0x43, 0xFF],
  ...encodedStr
]))`

Comment: here it shows error